# Django deferred jsonfield fetching

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use `defer` on my querysets. And then sometimes I need to directly fetch deferred field.
In Django 1.6.5 everything was alright.
But then I made upgrade to Django 1.10.5.

And now when I try something like `Document.objects.defer('cached_analysis').first().cached_analysis` I get `KeyError`. Turns out it only happens with custom fields `jsonfield.JSONField`. 'Native' django fields are working just fine.

And the error is:

```
File "/home/serf/dogbone/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonfield/subclassing.py", line 36, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.field.name]
KeyError: 'cached_analysis'
```

So, I have a feeling that changes in this patch `https://github.com/django/django/pull/6118 are not taken into account in jsonfield module (I use latest 2.0.1 version). I may be wrong though.

I tried to use some magic, like creating CustomJSONField(jsonfield.JSONField) with overwritten `__get__` method (to try to figure things out) but this method is not even called during reproduce, so I have failed miserably.